# Vieta's Formula for a Polynomial having the Square of the Roots of Another Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

For the root set $R=$ {$x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n$} of a given polynomial
$$P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots + a_0,$$
we have the Vieta's formula
$$v_1(R)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = -a_{n-1},$$
$$v_2(R) = \sum_{ (i,j)|1 \leq i,j \leq n \land i \neq j }x_ix_j=a_{n-2}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$v_n(R)=x_1x_2 \cdots x_n=(-1)^na_0.$$
I wonder if there is a general way to express $v_i(R^2)$ using the results from $v_i(R)$? By $R^2$ I refer to the root set obtained by squaring the elements in $R$.

Comment: Yes, any symmetric function e.g. v(R^2) can be expressed in terms of elementary symmetric functions (the v(R)s). This sometimes goes by the name of fundamental theorem of symmetric functions. Also see Newton identity for some related facts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much. I just read the link on the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials. I wonder if a way to determine an explicit recursive definition for my desired set of symmetric polynomials exists?

Comment: @usr0192 Thank you for naming the theorem and giving Newton's identity as an example. Could you please outline a way to determine a recursive formula for my system of symmetric polynomials analogous to Newton's identities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, even every symmetric polynomial in $x_1,\dots,x_r$ is a polynomial in the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $v_i(R)$, more commonly denoted by $e_i(x_1,\dots,x_r)$. This is the *fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials*, and [various proofs of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) give various general algorithms.

In your special case, here is a dedicated method to express the $w_i:=e_i(x_1^2,\dots,x_n^2)$s as polynomials in the $v_j:=e_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)$s, by expressing in two ways the monic polynomial with roots $\pm x_1,\dots,\pm x_n$:

$$P(X)(-1)^nP(-X)=\begin{cases}X^{2n}-w_1X^{2n-2}+w_2X^{2n-4}-\dots+(-1)^nw_n\\\left(X^n-v_1X^{n-1}+\dots+(-1)^nv_n\right)\left(X^n+v_1X^{n-1}+\dots+v_n\right).\end{cases}$$

Expanding the second line and equating the coefficients, we find:

$$\begin{cases}w_0&=1=:v_0\\w_1&=v_1^2-2v_2\\w_2&=v_2^2-2v_1v_3+2v_4\\w_3&=v_3^2-2v_2v_4+2v_1v_5-2v_6\\&\vdots\\w_k&=v_k^2+2\sum_{i=1}^{\min(k,n-k)}(-1)^iv_{k-i}v_{k+i}\\&\vdots\\w_n&=v_n^2.
\end{cases}$$

(In the expressions above for $w_1,w_2,w_3$, the convention is that $v_j=0$ whenever $j>n$.)

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a very beautiful proof.